# Express DELETE 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, express, router

I'm trying to Remove my `User` from the system, but I'm getting error **500 (Internal Server Error)**

I tried this with my `Product` and it still works fine. I didn't know where did I go wrong?

Below is my code

**`Router`**

```
router.get('/user-list/remove/:user_id', adminController.removeUser);
```

**`Service`**

```
async removeUser(user_id) {
    const userInDb = await this.userRepository.getById(user_id);
    if (userInDb) {
        await userInDb.destroy();
    } else {
        throw new Error();
    }
}
```

**`Controller`**

```
const removeUser = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const adminService = new AdminService();
    const data = req.params.user_id;
    await adminService.removeUser(data);
    res.send();
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ TRAVE: true, message: error });
}}
```

**`EJS`**

```
<a>
    <button class="deletebutton" value="<%= users[i].user_id %>">Delete</button>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $('.deletebutton').on("click", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var user_id = $(this).val();
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: `/admin/user-list/remove/${user_id}`,
                        method: 'get',
                        data: { user_id: user_id },
                        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                            if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == '200') {
                                $('.notification').html(`Delete done!`)
                            } else {
                                alert('Some error occurred try again');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            error.html(`${response.responseJSON.message}`);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
```

And this is what I get from `Console.log`

> GET http://localhost:5000/admin/user-list/remove/2?user_id=2 500 (Internal Server Error)

I tried with `router.delete` and `method: 'delete'` in the script but I get the same result. Where have I encountered the problem?
I have a Product table, I have user_id as a foreign key, is it a problem?

Comment: What are the error logs in your controller and service?

Comment: @ISAE I didn't see any errors in controller and service

Comment: You show a console.log with a 500 error, and in your controller you have the following code: `catch (error) {
    res.status(500)...`. any error message there?. could it be something with your db engin? what db / db driver are you using?